# lvm encrypted partition in arch linux giving not file system specified error after selecting grub option

Tags: linux, grub, arch-linux, lvm2

I'm try to configure lvm in my Arch Linux. But after configuring and booting, I'm getting this error:

> No filesystem type specified.

Everything that follows is the details.  Please click each link below for the associated images.

[Step-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5yJD.jpg) In step one i have shown my partition setup.

[Step-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW283.jpg) In this step i modified entry in grub.config and lvm.config mkinitcpio.config for hooks. After that i also executed mkinitcpio -p with preset.

Attaching mkinitcpio.conf file

```
# vim:set ft=sh
# MODULES
# The following modules are loaded before any boot hooks are
# run.  Advanced users may wish to specify all system modules
# in this array.  For instance:
#     MODULES=(piix ide_disk reiserfs)
MODULES=(dm_mod)

# BINARIES
# This setting includes any additional binaries a given user may
# wish into the CPIO image.  This is run last, so it may be used to
# override the actual binaries included by a given hook
# BINARIES are dependency parsed, so you may safely ignore libraries
BINARIES=()

# FILES
# This setting is similar to BINARIES above, however, files are added
# as-is and are not parsed in any way.  This is useful for config files.
FILES=""

# HOOKS
# This is the most important setting in this file.  The HOOKS control the
# modules and scripts added to the image, and what happens at boot time.
# Order is important, and it is recommended that you do not change the
# order in which HOOKS are added.  Run 'mkinitcpio -H <hook name>' for
# help on a given hook.
# 'base' is _required_ unless you know precisely what you are doing.
# 'udev' is _required_ in order to automatically load modules
# 'filesystems' is _required_ unless you specify your fs modules in MODULES
# Examples:
##   This setup specifies all modules in the MODULES setting above.
##   No raid, lvm2, or encrypted root is needed.
#    HOOKS=(base)
#
##   This setup will autodetect all modules for your system and should
##   work as a sane default
#    HOOKS=(base udev autodetect block filesystems)
#
##   This setup will generate a 'full' image which supports most systems.
##   No autodetection is done.
#    HOOKS=(base udev block filesystems)
#
##   This setup assembles a pata mdadm array with an encrypted root FS.
##   Note: See 'mkinitcpio -H mdadm' for more information on raid devices.
#    HOOKS=(base udev block mdadm encrypt filesystems)
#
##   This setup loads an lvm2 volume group on a usb device.
#    HOOKS=(base udev block lvm2 filesystems)
#
##   NOTE: If you have /usr on a separate partition, you MUST include the
#    usr, fsck and shutdown hooks.
HOOKS="base udev autodetect modconf block keyboard keymap resume encrypt lvm2 filesystems fsck"

# COMPRESSION
# Use this to compress the initramfs image. By default, gzip compression
# is used. Use 'cat' to create an uncompressed image.
#COMPRESSION="gzip"
#COMPRESSION="bzip2"
#COMPRESSION="lzma"
#COMPRESSION="xz"
#COMPRESSION="lzop"
#COMPRESSION="lz4"

# COMPRESSION_OPTIONS
# Additional options for the compressor
#COMPRESSION_OPTIONS=()
```

/etc/default/grub flag changed to GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR='Manjaro'
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet resume=UUID=471880b5-8b75-49da-9bea-20441bff363e"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# If you want to enable the save default function, uncomment the following
# line, and set GRUB_DEFAULT to saved.
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true

# Preload both GPT and MBR modules so that they are not missed
GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="part_gpt part_msdos"

GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y

# Uncomment to enable Hidden Menu, and optionally hide the timeout count
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=5
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true

# Uncomment to use basic console
GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT=console

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal
#GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE=auto

# Uncomment to allow the kernel use the same resolution used by grub
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep

# Uncomment if you want GRUB to pass to the Linux kernel the old parameter
# format "root=/dev/xxx" instead of "root=/dev/disk/by-uuid/xxx"
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY=true

# Uncomment and set to the desired menu colors.  Used by normal and wallpaper
# modes only.  Entries specified as foreground/background.
GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="light-gray/black"
GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="green/black"

# Uncomment one of them for the gfx desired, a image background or a gfxtheme
GRUB_BACKGROUND="/usr/share/grub/background.png"
#GRUB_THEME="/path/to/gfxtheme"

# Uncomment to get a beep at GRUB start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

In lvm.conf file i modified Use_lvm_metad=0

[Step-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdHLa.jpg) In this screenshot i'm getting password prompt. Please refer screenshot

[Step-4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTdNS.jpg)  After entering the password i'm getting the grub screen

[Step-5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qep0B.jpg) Selecting menu option getting error  "not file system specified error" .

Comment: @fixer1234 I added all the critical information and screenshot with this post itself.

Comment: @fixe1234 I have updated all my comments

Comment: Can you please unhold this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing little more R&D i was able to crack the issue. I'm just answering the question now.

The issue was due to root crypt partition was unable to mount due to 
below line was not present

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptdevice=UUID=47d9afe4-937f-4a11-b0c2-dda04c0ab14f:cryptlvm"
```

I'm attaching all my config . It will be usefull for others

disk structure

```
NAME              MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                 8:0    0   50G  0 disk  
|-sda1              8:1    0  512M  0 part  
| `-cryptboot     254:3    0  510M  0 crypt 
|   `-vgboot-boot 254:4    0  508M  0 lvm   /boot
`-sda2              8:2    0 49.5G  0 part  
  `-cryptlvm      254:0    0 49.5G  0 crypt 
    |-vgos-swap   254:1    0    4G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    `-vgos-root   254:2    0 45.5G  0 lvm   /
sr0                11:0    1  560M  0 rom
```

Grub file

```
# GRUB boot loader configuration

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="Arch"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptdevice=UUID=47d9afe4-937f-4a11-b0c2-dda04c0ab14f:cryptlvm"

# Preload both GPT and MBR modules so that they are not missed
GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="part_gpt part_msdos lvm"

# Uncomment to enable booting from LUKS encrypted devices
GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y

# Uncomment to enable Hidden Menu, and optionally hide the timeout count
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=5
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true

# Uncomment to use basic console
GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT=console

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal
#GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE=auto

# Uncomment to allow the kernel use the same resolution used by grub
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep

# Uncomment if you want GRUB to pass to the Linux kernel the old parameter
# format "root=/dev/xxx" instead of "root=/dev/disk/by-uuid/xxx"
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY=true

# Uncomment and set to the desired menu colors.  Used by normal and wallpaper
# modes only.  Entries specified as foreground/background.
#GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="light-blue/black"
#GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="light-cyan/blue"

# Uncomment one of them for the gfx desired, a image background or a gfxtheme
#GRUB_BACKGROUND="/path/to/wallpaper"
#GRUB_THEME="/path/to/gfxtheme"

# Uncomment to get a beep at GRUB start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

# Uncomment to make GRUB remember the last selection. This requires to
# set 'GRUB_DEFAULT=saved' above.
#GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"
#/dev/sda2: UUID="47d9afe4-937f-4a11-b0c2-dda04c0ab14f" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="aedc1116-02"
```

kernal args

```
# vim:set ft=sh
# MODULES
# The following modules are loaded before any boot hooks are
# run.  Advanced users may wish to specify all system modules
# in this array.  For instance:
#     MODULES=(piix ide_disk reiserfs)
MODULES=()

# BINARIES
# This setting includes any additional binaries a given user may
# wish into the CPIO image.  This is run last, so it may be used to
# override the actual binaries included by a given hook
# BINARIES are dependency parsed, so you may safely ignore libraries
BINARIES=()

# FILES
# This setting is similar to BINARIES above, however, files are added
# as-is and are not parsed in any way.  This is useful for config files.
FILES=()

# HOOKS
# This is the most important setting in this file.  The HOOKS control the
# modules and scripts added to the image, and what happens at boot time.
# Order is important, and it is recommended that you do not change the
# order in which HOOKS are added.  Run 'mkinitcpio -H <hook name>' for
# help on a given hook.
# 'base' is _required_ unless you know precisely what you are doing.
# 'udev' is _required_ in order to automatically load modules
# 'filesystems' is _required_ unless you specify your fs modules in MODULES
# Examples:
##   This setup specifies all modules in the MODULES setting above.
##   No raid, lvm2, or encrypted root is needed.
#    HOOKS=(base)
#
##   This setup will autodetect all modules for your system and should
##   work as a sane default
#    HOOKS=(base udev autodetect block filesystems)
#
##   This setup will generate a 'full' image which supports most systems.
##   No autodetection is done.
#    HOOKS=(base udev block filesystems)
#
##   This setup assembles a pata mdadm array with an encrypted root FS.
##   Note: See 'mkinitcpio -H mdadm' for more information on raid devices.
#    HOOKS=(base udev block mdadm encrypt filesystems)
#
##   This setup loads an lvm2 volume group on a usb device.
#    HOOKS=(base udev block lvm2 filesystems)
#
##   NOTE: If you have /usr on a separate partition, you MUST include the
#    usr, fsck and shutdown hooks.
HOOKS=(base udev autodetect modconf block encrypt lvm2 filesystems keyboard fsck)

# COMPRESSION
# Use this to compress the initramfs image. By default, gzip compression
# is used. Use 'cat' to create an uncompressed image.
#COMPRESSION="gzip"
#COMPRESSION="bzip2"
#COMPRESSION="lzma"
#COMPRESSION="xz"
#COMPRESSION="lzop"
#COMPRESSION="lz4"

# COMPRESSION_OPTIONS
# Additional options for the compressor
#COMPRESSION_OPTIONS=()
```

UUID list

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="447df32a-3710-492a-9f72-e09a40d9ec8d" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="aedc1116-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="47d9afe4-937f-4a11-b0c2-dda04c0ab14f" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="aedc1116-02"
/dev/sr0: UUID="2018-05-01-05-08-12-00" LABEL="ARCH_201805" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="0b99c0ac" PTTYPE="dos"
/dev/mapper/cryptlvm: UUID="wakG2q-FXiE-KN7f-6Txm-Yupa-NFnn-pOeRBZ" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/vgos-swap: UUID="828c1d32-ecf7-4c6a-92b7-03fd348ff674" TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/vgos-root: UUID="6e37158b-1e6f-43fa-8dad-4c42acaf0105" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/cryptboot: UUID="lDviz3-lyiN-kb9M-AKYZ-2qx5-GBD6-IWi23u" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/vgboot-boot: UUID="dee4c02a-c9b8-42e9-9859-47e9d50e7bc3" TYPE="ext4"
```